# Rollie pollies - are they harmful to vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, insects, root-vegetables, bugs, leaf-vegetables

I have a vegetable raised box where I grow various vegetables in spring and summer. I noticed quite a few Rollie pollies in the box. Wondering if they will harm my vegetable crop this year and what if anything I can do to prevent that. [image]

Comment: By Rollie pollies are you referring to Woodlice?

Comment: Added a picture for clarification

Comment: Woodlice don't eat plants. But if you have enough of them to see them wandering around in the open during the daytime, that suggests you have some decomposing material somewhere (e.g. rotting wood) and **that** could be a problem, if it is providing a home fungal diseases, or a "nest-box" for other insect pests. If you keep things generally clean and tidy, the woodlice will just go to live some place else.

Comment: Are woodlice and pill bugs one and the same thing?

Answer (score 9):

The wood at the bottom of the bed looks pretty dark in comparison to the rest of the side. It's most likely that the woodlice are feeding off a decaying box, rather than anything in the bed. They'll only be recycling nutrients from the wood into the bed. They'll cause very little damage if any, mainly to soft fruit or seedling. If anything, they're highly beneficial to the soil structure, aiding the composting process and maintaining biodiversity within the soil

[RHS - Woodlice](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=723)

Comment: and they are just cool all round, one of the few, or only, land dwelling crustaceans

Comment: Thanks for the info. The Rollie pollies are everywhere. Good to hear they are not harmful